# how to get the key value from the nested hash inside the array?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, hash

I have a array which is inside a hash. I want know the result of the student (pass/fail) using the following array. First I have to match them with particular standard and compare their marks with the hash pass and fails. And I want to get the key pass or fail based on their mark. How to achieve this using Ruby?

```
array = [
  {
     :standard =>1
     :pass=>{:tamil=>30,:eng=>25,:math=>35},
     :fail=>{:tamil=>10,:eng=>15,:maths=>20}
  },
  {
    :standard =>2,
    :pass=>{:tamil=>40,:eng=>35,:math=>45},
    :fail=>{:tamil=>20,:eng=>25,:maths=>30}
  }
]
```

Comment: So what output would you expect here?

Comment: The result of student - pass or fail

Comment: @Jaklin - I am not getting, you have both pass and fail for every student, so how you want to identify who is pass or who is fail

Comment: @Jaklin -  and for every student there is different criteria of pass and fail

Comment: Thanks for reply. I have a student object that has attribute of standard ,marks for tamil, eng and maths subject. I want to pass that student object and get their result that is pass or fail by using this structure.

Comment: @Sontya-That is standard for each standard i have different criteria of pass.

Comment: @Jaklin : Could you be more specific. It seems that the array object is your criteria array and you will input a student array with his marks and then decide whether he passes or fails

Comment: @Jalkin - ok, got it. So what input you will provide, as a student array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@student is assumed to be defined

```
standard = array.select {|standard| standard[:standard] == @student.standard}
eng_pass = @student.eng_mark  >= standard[:pass][:eng]
eng_fail = @student.eng_mark  <= standard[:fail][:eng]

return [eng_pass, eng_fail, whatever_else_you_want]
```

So on and forth for various topics.

Comment: Thank you so much. I want to check whether the user pass or fail based on all subject.

Comment: I again want to loop into :pass and :fail hash. After comparing the student all subject marks that two array i have to find whether the user is pass or fail

Comment: that already tells if if you passed, eng_pass and eng_fail are booleans.

Answer (score 0):

The syntax in reading values from this structure is something like:

```
array[0][:pass][:eng]
```

and accordingly you can do the comparison as usual in batch:

```
for i in 0..@students_array.length
   num = # student's score
   standard = # something like array[0][:pass][:eng]

   if num > standard
      # something like 'put "You passed!"'
   end
end
```